# Can't use EJB from Web Application

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have the next problem while trying to develope a REST app using **JPA** and **EJB**'s.

I have 3 projects in NetBeans (same workspace, just projects, not EAR or that weird stuff):

- One of them is a Java Application in which I created some entity classes from a database. Inside of the same project, I created other package containing the controller classes from the entities. I tested the project creating a java main class and using the controllers.
- The other project is a EJB module, it as simple as a package and the next class inside of it:

  ```
  package com.studentejb;
  import java.util.List;
  import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
  import javax.ejb.Stateless;
  import studentdao.StudentTO;
  import studentdao.StudentJpaController;

  @Stateless
  @LocalBean
  public class StudentEJB {

      private StudentJpaController studentDao = new StudentJpaController();

      public List<StudentTO> findStudents() {
          return studentDao.findStudentTO();
      }
  }
  ```

As you can see, I imported the previous JAR project (the one with the entity's controllers). I also tested this EJB project with a java main class and it worked.

- The last project is a web application, as you can imagine I want to use the EJB modules of the previous project but I get the following errors while trying to enter to the resource `http://localhost:8080/studentWeb/student/`:

  ```
  12:00:12,384 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-2) UT005023:    Exception handling request to /studentWeb/student/hola:     com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError:     java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2201)
  at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3937)
  at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3941)
  at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4824)
  at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:49)
  .
  .
  .

  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  at studentdao.StudentJpaController.<init>(StudentJpaController.java:40)
  at com.studentejb.StudentEJB.<init>(StudentEJB.java:23)
  at com.studentweb.Resources.<init>(Resources.java:52)
  at com.studentweb.Resources$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  .
  .
  .

  ... 58 more
  Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to locate persistence units 
  at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:99)
  at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:86)
  at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:67)
  at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
  at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
  at studentdao.EntityProvider.<clinit>(EntityProvider.java:20)
  ... 80 more

  Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid persistence.xml.
  Error parsing XML [line : -1, column : -1] : cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the     declaration of element 'persistence'.

  at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.validate(PersistenceXmlParser.java:377)
  at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.loadUrl(PersistenceXmlParser.java:310)
  at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.parsePersistenceXml(PersistenceXmlParser.java:114)
  at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.doResolve(PersistenceXmlParser.java:104)
  at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.locatePersistenceUnits(PersistenceXmlParser.java:86)
  at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:95)
  ... 85 more
  ```

Here is the code of the web app (Resources.java):

```
@Path("/student")
public class Resources {
    @EJB
    private StudentEJB studentEjb;

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    public Resources() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, NamingException {
        studentEjb = new StudentEJB();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getJson() {
        return Response.ok(studentEjb.findStudents()).build();
    }
}
```

So I am using 2 JARs for the web project, the one with the EJB modules and the other with the entities and controllers..

Here is the persistence.xml generated by the **JPA** project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="studentJPAPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <!-- <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> -->
    <class>studentjpa.Address</class>
    <class>studentjpa.Phone</class>
    <class>studentjpa.Student</class>
    <class>studentjpa.Email</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=tca_student_db;integratedSecurity=true"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="xxxx"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxxx"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Thank you!

Comment: The error message is saying `Invalid persistence.xml.` - can you post your persistence.xml to the question please

Comment: You need to create interface for ejb. The ejb jar has not to be in war but deployed directly in jee sever.

Comment: I have an interface for the EJB module (inside the same EJB project), but since I'm using `@LocalBean` annotation, it isn't necessary to implement that interface isn't it ? @Mr_Thorynque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid
>   persistence.xml. Error parsing XML [line : -1, column : -1] :
>   cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the     declaration of element 'persistence'.

Here :

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
```

xmlns :`http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence` doesn't match with the namespace in xsischemaLocation  which is `http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence`

Try to use the same in both :

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"   
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
```

Comment: No problem but I am sure that the problem is in that file :) I updated my answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much it works!!!, I have been trying to make it works for hours, I'm pretty new with this concepts like ejb and jpa, Thanks

Comment: ejb and jpa are big chunks but xml too :) Good luck for the next  :)